# Как исправить ошибку в aiogram при вызове /alert

Tags: python, aiogram

У меня есть файл bot.py:

```
import logging
from os import get_terminal_size
from typing import Text
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, executor, types
from requests.api import get
import config
import requests
import json
from aiogram.dispatcher.filters import Text

def get_bitcoin_price() -> int:
    # Делаем запрос на получение цены биткоина
    response = requests.get('https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/simple/price?ids=bitcoin&vs_currencies=usd').text
    bitcoinjson = json.loads(response)
    return int(bitcoinjson["bitcoin"]["usd"])


# Объект бота
bot = Bot(config.token)

# Диспетчер для бота
dp = Dispatcher(bot)

# Включаем логирование, чтобы не пропустить важные сообщения
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)

# Хэндлер на команду /price
@dp.message_handler(commands=["price"])
async def priceb(message: types.Message):
    await message.answer(f"Цена биткоина = {get_bitcoin_price()}")

@dp.message_handler(commands=["alert"])   
async def alarm(message: types.Message):
    mean = int(message.text[6:])
    n = False
    while n == False:
        if mean < get_bitcoin_price():
            await message.answer(f"Цена биткоина пересекла вашу отметку {mean}")
            n = True

        
    


if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Запуск бота
    executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=True)
```

при вызове /alert происходит ошибка:ERROR:asyncio:Task exception was never retrieved
future: <Task finished name='Task-14' coro=<Dispatcher._process_polling_updates() done, defined at C:\Users\Vladimir\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\dispatcher.py:409> exception=JSONDecodeError('Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)')>
Traceback (most recent call last):
raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

Comment: попробуйте функцию `get_bitcoin_price` изменить следующим образом`return requests.get('https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/simple/price?ids=bitcoin&vs_currencies=usd').json()['bitcoin']['usd']`

Comment: Не помогло. Скорее  всего ошибка в команде /alert, но я не знаю какая

Comment: у меня все прекрасно работает с моим кодом. Ошибка в функции с получением курса, написано же. Можете сделать `print (response)` и посмотреть что вы получаете

Comment: print (response) также не работает, пишу /alert и выходит ошибка

Comment: добавьте print(response) в свою функцию и посмотрите что возвращает. Мой код выше прекрасно работает